# Play OSS plugin strips first char from url or license

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using play-services-oss-licenses plugin to include OSS linceses in my app.

I use latest version (16.0.0) and use it as described here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource.

Majority of licenses have stripped the first character from the url or the license itself. See images. Any ideas where the bug is?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This seems like a bug. Will take a look.

In the meanwhile, can you help by updating with your app's build.gradle? May be due to something happening with the specific libraries used and how the plugin is handling those licenses.

And this is happening to all licenses, or only a few?

Comment: Not all, but many. It happens for longer time, I have dependencies quite up to date.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this issue locally. What version of the oss-licenses-plugin are you using? I am looking at it with the latest released 0.9.2 version.

Comment: @zfromg I'm using com.google.gms:oss-licenses:0.9.2, I can try the 0.9.3 but I thing it won't help. Maybe it's some combination of other plugins :/

Comment: @zfromg Ok, it seems it's a bug in specific env setup. It's ok On my CI. Any idea which differences I should look for? The main is I use windows, CI is linux :) All others should be the same...

Comment: You can take a look at how the plugin works here: https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/tree/master/oss-licenses-plugin. From the looks of it, this appears to be some off-by-one error when indexing into the third_party_licenses resource in your app's built .apk (i.e. truncating one character). Given your Windows setup, could this be some mismatch between character encodings which causes the off-by-one error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in `com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:0.9.4`. (They've fixed some UTF-8 bug.)